# C++ method with type

Tags: c++, class, templates, return

Is there some way to use template solution or something in this example? Now parse() function return type in class C is different, depending which type is used.

I have class A:

```
class A {

    std::vector<SomeClass*> parseData(const char *data);
}
```

And then I have class B

```
class B {

    std::string parseData(const char *data); }
```

Then I want to call call right class method in class C:

```
class C {

    std::vector<SomeClass*> parse { A::parseData(_data); }
    std::string parse { B::parseData(_data); }

    void setData(std:string data) { _data = data; }

    std:string _data;
}

int main()
{
    C c1.setData(data_with_many_strings_and_numbers);
    C c2.setData(data_with_one_string);
    std::vector<SomeClass*> someClassData = c1.parse();
    std:string someString = c2.parse();
}
```

Comment: The functions seem to do different things. Why wouldn't you give them different names and avoid this problem altogether?

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you have two separate methods for those calls as they perform different tasks. Consider changing this implementation to something of the sort:

```
class C {

    std::vector<SomeClass*> parseVector { A::parseData(_data); }
    std::string parseString { B::parseData(_data); }

    void setData(std:string data) { _data = data; }

    std:string _data;
}

int main()
{
    C c1.setData(data_with_many_strings_and_numbers);
    C c2.setData(data_with_one_string);
    std::vector<SomeClass*> someClassData = c1.parseVector();
    std:string someString = c2.parseString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No.  You can't do what you're trying to do the way you're trying to do it.  Parsing is essentially a runtime problem and you can't decide what to return on the fly like that.  You'll need to make the types returned subtypes somehow, either directly or via a wrapper that can tell you what type you've read.  You can then register parsers with a chain of responsibility.  Registering with this chain of responsibility could benefit from templated function calls but it'll need to wrap those in a type-hiding encapsulator than polymorphises your static types to call the same, named function in those types (probably a waste of time...may as well just subtype an abstract base unless you're forced to do otherwise).

At any rate, you need a whole different approach than what you're doing now.